# how to write and call a function without object \ when we dont want to call with an object

Tags: c++

i am using different classes and also objects relavent to those different classes. Now, i want to write a seperate function which use to joint two vector to another vector. where should i write these type of seperate functions. Can i use a new header file for that? actually, i made a new header file (ConnectedSegment.h) and put my function under that. but, i got this error.

```
43 D:myex\ConnectedSegment.h non-member function `std::vector<int>& NeighboursToGivenValue(std::map<int, std::vector<int> >&, int, int)' cannot have `const' method qualifier 

D:\myex\Detects\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [Detects.o] Error 1
```

Here is my code of the function:

```
vector<int> & NeighboursToGivenValue(map<int, vector<int> > &adjacency, 
                                              int s1, int s2) const
{
  vector<int>::const_iterator any;
  vector<int>::iterator is_any;
  vector<int> *neighbours2both = new vector<int>;
  int i;

  neighbours2both->reserve(adjacency[s1].size() + adjacency[s2].size());
  neighbours2both->insert(neighbours2both->end(), adjacency[s1].begin(),adjacency[s1].end ());

  vector<int>& neighbours2s2=adjacency[s2];        
  for (any=neighbours2s2.begin(); any!=neighbours2s2.end(); any++){            
       is_any = find (neighbours2both->begin(), neighbours2both->end(), *any);           
       if(is_any == neighbours2both->end()){
          if(s1 != *any) neighbours2both->push_back(*any);
       }
  }
  for (i=0; i<neighbours2both->size(); i++){
       neighbours2both->erase(neighbours2both->begin() + i);
  }
  return(*neighbours2both);
}
```

In here, I got the values for the `adjacency()` by using another class called `MyPoint`.
So I used `myxyz.adjacency()` to accomadate the values for this adjacency. Now I dont want to call the same class `MyPoint` for calling function `NeighboursToGivenValue`. So, 
could you tell me where I should write this function. Alternatively, if I write this function inside the `MyPoint` class, how can I call this function without an object of that class.

Comment: Kindly format your question so the code is at all legible.

Comment: @g_niro: I tried fixing your question, but the language is very hard to understand. Please read it again and try to fix sentences like *where i should write these type of seperate functions are writing*.

Comment: Please use the `{}` button to format your code. Simply select the code with the mouse, and press the `{}` button in the editor. If we can't read your code, it's very hard to answer your question.

Comment: sorry, i am modifying my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These *free* functions can be in the header (will need to be declared `inline` as Pedro highlights in his comment) - or they can be declared in the header and defined in an implementation file - for example,

```
#header

vector<int>& join_int_vector(vector<int> const& lhs, vector<int> const& rhs);

# cpp

vector<int>& join_int_vector(vector<int> const& lhs, vector<int> const& rhs)
{
 // do stuff
}
```

The problem you face is that you can *only have const member functions* - i.e. free functions (and static functions) cannot be `const` - it doesn't mean anything.

btw. don't construct a vector dynamically and return a reference to it, i.e:

```
vector<int> *neighbours2both = new vector<int>;
:
return (*neighbours2both);
```

The callee has no awareness that this object needs to be manually cleaned up - in this case, return by value.

```
vector<int> join_int_vector(vector<int> const& lhs, vector<int> const& rhs)
{
  vector<int> neighbours2both;
  :
  return neighbours2both;
}
```

EDIT: for functions defined in the header itself, something like this:

```
inline vector<int> join_int_vector(vector<int> const& lhs, vector<int> const& rhs)
{
  vector<int> neighbours2both;
  :
  return neighbours2both;
}
```

note the use of the keyword `inline` - this prevents multiple definition errors if this header is included in multiple translation units.

Comment: If the free functions are defined in the header, they will probably need to be `inline` so you don't get multiple definition errors.

Comment: @ Nim., thank you very much for the clear example. but, I am not sure whether i should work with the inline. so, if i am using h file and cpp file for the declaration and implementation of free functions, Do i need inline? may be you could give me the example with inline to get more clear idea. many thanks...

Comment: in that case you don't need `inline` - it's only required if you plan to put the implementation in the header file as well.

Comment: sorry,, i couldnt fix the error yet. now i am getting this error massege.    [Linker error] undefined reference to `NeighboursToGivenSegments(std::map<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >&, int, int)'

Comment: Did you compile and link the implementation file which has this function?

Comment: it seems the compiler doesnt compile these two files. it just skippng these two.. i will check it and let you know later. thanks

Comment: when i put everything (function prototype and implementation) to the h file and make it inline then, it compiles.

Comment: Yes, means you've not compiled the separate translation unit and linked it in - e.g, first compile the unit with the function `g++ -c unit unit.cpp` - the resulting object file should be used in compiling the main application `g++ -o main main.cpp unit.o` - now the implementation should be available (do this for your compiler).